# Meteor + React: Meteor.subscribe('Collection', limit) Triggers Rerender Every List Element

Tags: reactjs, meteor, publish-subscribe

I have a Meteor subscription with some settings, so that I do not publish my whole collection server side. The subscription will be fetched within a `createContainer()` from `meteor/react-meteor-data` and displayed in a simple `<ul>` list, where I also added the document.id to the `<li>` element as a key.

Unfortunately as soon as I increase the settings.limit in the subscription 2nd subscription argument (`Meteor.subscripte('Collections', settings.limit`) the whole `<ul>` list rerenders? What can I do to increase the publication limit, while only adding the new list elements?

P.S. When I publish the total Collection and change the limit in my client via `Collection.find({}, {limit: newLimit}).fetch()`, react is working as expected: leaving the old elements as they are and just adding the new ones!

---

**Client Side**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Locations } from '/both/collections/locations.js';
import { Events } from '/both/collections/events.js';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

class Content extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.renderLocations = this.renderLocations.bind(this);
  }

  renderLocations() {
    return this.props.locations.map(function(location) {
      return (<li key={location._id} >{location.name}</li>);
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return !this.props.loading && (
      <div>
    <ul>
      {this.renderLocations()}
    </ul>
      <h1 onClick={this.props.increaseLimit}> Limit </h1>
      <div style={{marginBottom: "100px"}}></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default createContainer((props) => {
  const settings = {
    limit: props.limit,
  }
  const locationsSubscribe = Meteor.subscribe('Locations', settings);
  const loading = !locationsSubscribe.ready();
  if(loading) {
    return { loading };
  } else {
    const _locations = Locations.find({}, {fields: { name: 1}, sort: { name: 1 }}).fetch();

    return {
      loading, 
      locations: _locations,
      increaseLimit: props.increaseLimit,
    };
  }
}, Content);
```

---

**Server Side**

```
Meteor.publish('Locations', function(settings) {
  return Locations.find({}, {limit: settings.limit, sort: { name: 1} } );
});
```

---

**The Collection.find().fetch() response**

```
[
  {
    "name": "3-Master Bike-Style",
    "_id": "N9rWyZMdxEe6jhNW2"
  },
  {
    "name": "43einhalb",
    "_id": "bPgpBm59LohGLaAsf"
  },
  {
    "name": "A&B Döner",
    "_id": "qTNMk73ThvaPxGWqM"
  },
  {
    "name": "A.T.U ",
    "_id": "aWzSmp2zZ8etDhHk6"
  },
  {
    "name": "AIKO Sushibar - Hot Wok",
    "_id": "9pQJgeBNo5gFRkKdF"
  },
  {
    "name": "AXA Stefan Hahn",
    "_id": "d9f6mTrSTGCoeKPbP"
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you share the console.log for your collection data on 2 subscription. There may be some logical bug. Please make sure you are not pushing new data to old array.

Comment: @PankajJatav you mean the fetched array? Returned by the Collection.find().fetch()?

Comment: Yes please share that.

Comment: @PankajJatav I added you the code and tried to copy the `_location` variable

Comment: Can you also share the server code. Your client code looks Ok.

Comment: @PankajJatav here you go, btw thx for the time!

Comment: Please check my answer. And let me know if you find this helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your server side logic.

**Your current code:**

```
Meteor.publish('Locations', function(settings) {
  return Locations.find({}, {limit: settings.limit, sort: { name: 1} } );
});
```

This will send n number of doc, basically you are 10, 20, 30 and so on docs to the client.

**Fix** : You need to skip the previous doc.

**Solution:**

```
Meteor.publish('Locations', function(settings) {
  return Locations.find({}, {skip: settings.skip, limit: settings.limit, sort: { name: 1} } );
});
```

Or

```
Meteor.publish('Locations', function(settings) {
  var skip = settings.pageNumber * settings.number_of_record_per_page; //change variable according to you
  return Locations.find({}, {skip: settings.limit, limit: settings.limit, sort: { name: 1} } );
});
```

Comment: I am not 100% sure if this will work. With your server-side solution you would send the new locations, overwriting the old locations saved in the props. I'll try and let you know and thx a lot for the help!

Comment: This is the solution for creating pagination things in meteor. A better and good way.

Comment: Yes with this fix only the "new" published lcoations are displayed. You need additionally to the new locations join the old ones, which I did now with the `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` in the state of my content component

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally found the Problem: 
The every time the limit changes the `createContainer()` subscribes again to the published collection! Meaning that it sends new props to my *Content* component, which triggers a rerender! For the short moment it takes to resubscribe the location array, which is saved as a prop, will be overridden by an empty array, which one only notes as a flash in the screen. So for a short second there will be no content displayed and then the new props with the correct locations array is transmitted.

The solutions now to `concat()` the new location array into the state of the *Content* component via `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` whenever there are new locations to add. Then one can compare the old and new state, within the `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)` and only update when the state is changing!